# How to make contextual framed letters get proportional size automatically?

Tags: fonts, subscripts, superscripts, fontsize

I am creating a question sheet using a method (I don't know the exact name, maybe bubble sheet format) as follows:

[image]

My question is how to improve the appearance such that the framed letters get proportional size based on the context. If the frame letter must work as an exponent, it must be smaller. If it works as a lower index in integral or sum, it also must be smaller.

Here is my code snippet after "normalization" :-)

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,dvips,cmyk]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bera}


\fboxsep=2pt
\fboxrule=0.8pt

\newcommand{\boxy}[1]{\ensuremath{\,\fbox{\;\,{\color{red}\bf#1}\,\;}\,}}

\newcommand{\ltr}[1]{{\color{red}\bf#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
Each letter \ltr{A}, \ltr{B}, \ltr{C}, etc in the equations represents a numeral (from 0 to 9) or the minus sign ($-$).


\[
\int_{\boxy{A}}^{\boxy{B}}f(x)\,\textrm{d}x=\frac{1-\boxy{P}}{\boxy{Q}+\boxy{R}}
\]

\[
-2 x^{\boxy{XYZ}}-\boxy{W}\sqrt{\boxy{V}+1}
\]

\[
\sum_{i=\boxy{A}}^{\boxy{BC}}=\tan\left(\boxy{D}-\boxy{E}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `\text` command, it takes the correct font setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\fboxsep=2pt
\fboxrule=0.8pt

\newcommand\boxy[1]{\text{\,\fbox{\;\,{\color{red}$\mathbf{#1}$}\,\;}\,}}

\newcommand{\ltr}[1]{{\color{red}\bf#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
Each letter \ltr{A}, \ltr{B}, \ltr{C}, etc in the equations 
represents a numeral (from 0 to 9) or the minus sign ($-$).
%
\[
\int\limits_{\boxy{A}}^{\boxy{B}}f(x)\,\textrm{d}x=\frac{1-\boxy{P}}{\boxy{Q}+\boxy{R}}
\]
%
\[
-2 x^{\boxy{XYZ}}-\boxy{W}\sqrt{\boxy{V}+1}
\]
%
\[
\sum_{i=\boxy{A}}^{\boxy{BC}}=\tan\left(\boxy{D}-\boxy{E}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised! Why does this work?

Comment: @Hendrik: `\text` expands to `\text@` which expands to a `\mathchoice` which uses `\everymath` to set the appropriate style.

Comment: @Hendrik: it uses the definitions from mathcoice: `\let\f@size#2\selectfont`

Comment: @TH.: Ah, `\everymath` is something I'm not well-acquainted with. No wonder I didn't get it.

Comment: thanks for giving me the simplest or most compact (hopely) solution.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use `\mathpalette`: Replace your definition of `\boxy` with

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\boxy}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathpalette\boxy@helper{#1}}}
\newcommand{\boxy@helper}[2]{\,\fbox{\;\,{\color{red}$\m@th#1\mathbf{#2}$}\,\;}\,}
\makeatother
```

Note that I made another change to your macro: I use `$`s and `\mathbf` in the `\fbox`, and I added `\m@th` to ensure that you don't get additional horizontal space.

Comment: Might be worth adding `\m@th` as well.

Comment: @TH.: Thanks! Hope that what I wrote is correct.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Even though your solution and Herbert's work, Herbert's is simpler than yours. So I choose Herbert's. :-)

Comment: @xport: Good choice!